# Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

During my training, I'm working on a website and we use Ruby on Rails. We need to send mails to users so I created a mailer.

I have tried to put the smtp in both `development.rb` and `environment.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: '0.0.0.0:3000'}
config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = 'smtp'
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  adress: $SMTP_SERVER,
  port: $PORT,
  from: $MAIL,

  enable_starttls_auto: true
  #authentication: 'login'
}
```

It tells me that the error comes from this method line 6

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now

      format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
      format.json { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I have set the port to `587` but i keep getting the error:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost"
>   port 25

It looks as if another file was overwriting my settings. I also saw that it might be related to my ssh key not being authorized by the server.

Do know what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you're supposed to use an email service like SendGrid or Amazon SES, since those work locally. I'm not sure how you're supposed to get the built-in Rails mailers to work at all. I'm certainly not going to deploy something to a server when it doesn't even work locally.

Answer (score 22):

First of all, when developing on localhost, it's common to *not* actually send out mail, rather to treat that as a deployment detail and stick with the Rails default behavior which is to spit out the mail headers and contents into the console STDOUT (where you can verify that the text looks right). Is there a specific reason why you need to test sending messages in the dev environment?

Secondly, you mentioned that you set the SMTP settings in both development.rb and environment.rb. You shouldn't need to set these settings twice; in general I'd use `development.rb` for settings specific to the dev environment, and `environment.rb` only for settings that will always apply to all environments (dev, tests, and on the live deployed server). So if you're setting the same settings in both development.rb and environment.rb, I'd start by removing one or the other; redundancy will only make your job harder down the road.

Finally, to troubleshoot this I'd start by asking Rails what its settings are rather than waiting for the mail delivery to fail. Try the following:

- Start up `rails console`
- Enter `Rails.configuration.action_mailer.smtp_settings` and compare the resulting hash against your expectations. This hash should contain the port and domain settings that are used when sending out all mail (in the current environment), so if ActionMailer is trying the wrong port then I'd expect the port to be wrong here too.

Where are you setting `$SMTP_SERVER`, `$PORT` and `$MAIL`? Is there any reason you aren't using Rails' convention for environment variables, `ENV['SMTP_SERVER']` etc.?

Hope some of that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to test sending messages to understand how it works (I'm new with Ruby on Rails) and I want to be sure that it works correctly because I'm not alone on this project and I don't want to broke everything.
I figured out that the problem came from the wifi of the university that didn't allow me access to the SMTP.

Comment: OK, sounds fair. But just to be clear, my impression is Rails assumes you don't care about sending messages in development mode; it makes it easy to verify the contents of the message but stops short of the SMTP connection, which is generally treated as a deployment & server config detail (not part of the Rails app code itself).

Comment: My problem is now solved, the person in charge fixed the wifi and then I had another error which was because I wrote `"smtp"` instead of `:smtp`.

Comment: Upvote for opening the console and checking the settings there.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = 'smtp'
```

with

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Ensure your Rails.configuration.action_mailer.smtp_settings is symbolized keys

Comment: or remove it entirely as `:smtp` is the default now

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error message well developing my own application. What I discovered is that as I was not actually sending any emails in a development environment I needed to change one of the lines in the configuration file found at: `/your_apps_name/config/environments/development.rb`

from

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

to

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

This was causing my application to raise errors when emails were not successfully delivered, and I wasn't actually sending emails so of course they were not being delivered successfully.

Comment: Useful in Development Environment

Answer (score 2):

The app might be using `mailcatcher` gem for all outbound emails on development, which you haven't installed or don't have running. At least that was my issue. Check out https://mailcatcher.me and follow the instructions given.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` line.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue when running `Sidekiq::Worker.drain_all` in my RSpec tests, and it was driving me crazy because I had `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in my `config/environments/test.rb`.

The solution was to set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` in my `config/environments/development.rb`, which is confusing because the implication is that my `config/environments/development.rb` is overriding my `config/environments/test.rb` in my RSpec tests.

Regardless, this might fix the problem for others.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone clumsy like me, I got this message when I had everything set up perfectly in my app, but I had simply forgotten to run the command that adds the mailing addon in my production environment. In my case, that line was `heroku addons:create mailgun:starter`.