# How to use mailer in Rails 6.1?

Tags: javascript, ruby, forms, mailer, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm currently trying to create a contact us form where users can send a report of any kind to my personal email address. For the sake of this example let's call it `my-email-address@email.com`.

For the moment I don't care a lot about the user's email. Let's say I'm going to use the following information.

- `from:` `"my-email-address@email.com"`
- `to:` `"my-email-address@email.com"`
- `subject:` `"a subject name"`

**STEP 1:** I created my form in `views/home/contact_us.html.erb` with an AJAX POST request:

```
<form id="sendEmailForm">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" placeholder="Enter a subject (Optional)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Please write your name, company-name, and what you would like to achieve." id="exampleFormControlTextarea3" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Send Email</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#sendEmailForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        let final_json_data = {
            email: document.getElementById("exampleFormControlInput1").value,
            subject: document.getElementById("exampleFormControlInput2").value,
            content: document.getElementById("exampleFormControlTextarea3").value
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/home/send_email_to_server',
            type: "POST",
            data: {emailDetails: final_json_data},
            success: function(result) { 
                alert("ajax request OK!");
            },
            fail: function(result) {
                alert("ajax has failed")
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

**STEP 2:** My Home Controller and routes.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def contact_us
    puts "GETTING THE PAGE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
  end
  

  def send_email_to_server
    
    @emailDetails = params[:emailDetails]

    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    puts "     Store email details on server"

    puts @emailDetails['email']
    puts @emailDetails['subject']
    puts @emailDetails['content']
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"


    ContactUsMailer.notify_server_via_email(@emailDetails['email'], @emailDetails['subject']).deliver
  
    puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    

  end
end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/contact_us'
  post 'home/send_email_to_server'
end
```

**STEP 3:** Modified `application_mailer.rb` to have a default `from-email`:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "my-email-address@email.com"
    layout 'mailer'
end
```

**STEP 4:** Modified `contact_us_mailer.rb` to handle the request with the captured parameters:

```
class ContactUsMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def notify_server_via_email(toEmail, aSubject)
        puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
        puts "     Trying to send an email . . . "

        @email = toEmail
        @subject = aSubject
        puts @email
        puts @subject

        puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"

        mail(
            to: @email,
            subject: @subject
        )
    end
end
```

**STEP 4:** Then in the `views/contact_us_mailer` I created a new file called `notify_server_via_email.html.erb` and added the following content:

```
<h1> hello world </h1>
```

---

So here is what happens in order:

1. User fills form and submits the button.
2. AJAX POST REQUEST to `/home/send_email_to_server`
3. Server receives request and catches parameters and executes `mail()` function

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Started POST "/home/send_email_to_server" for ::1 at 2021-07-03 18:01:00 +0300
Processing by HomeController#send_email_to_server as */*
  Parameters: {"emailDetails"=>{"email"=>"my-email-address@email.com", "subject"=>"some new subject", "content"=>"a text example"}}



>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
     Store email details on server
my-email-address@email.com
some new subject
a text example
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
     Trying to send an email . . .
my-email-address@email.com
some new subject
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>



  Rendering layout layouts/mailer.html.erb
  Rendering contact_us_mailer/notify_server_via_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered contact_us_mailer/notify_server_via_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 70)
  Rendered layout layouts/mailer.html.erb (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 241)
ContactUsMailer#notify_server_via_email: processed outbound mail in 14.0ms
Delivered mail 60e07bace69f9_27544024-497@DESKTOP-MQJ3IGG.mail (30045.8ms)
Date: Sat, 03 Jul 2021 18:01:00 +0300
From: my-email-address@email.com
To: my-email-address@email.com
Message-ID: <60e07bace69f9_27544024-497@DESKTOP-MQJ3IGG.mail>
Subject: some new subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
  </body>
</html>

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30095ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 11373)



EOFError (end of file reached):

app/controllers/home_controller.rb:35:in `send_email_to_server'
```

I have no idea what is causing the 500 Internal server error. I'm currently working on the development side and I'm aware that I shouldn't be doing this but it's just for testing purposes, I'm not aiming to keep this configuration forever. Also, I came across this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009419/connection-refused-connect2-for-localhost-port-25-rails/31009864) which is similar with my issue, but there is no clear answer since that was the university wifi preventing an smtp request from working. I'm trying from a home wifi.

Also for additional reference here is my `development.rb` commands for `action_mailer`:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'localhost',
    :port    => 3000
  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is raised by library [net/protocol.rb#227](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ac6924e10eed6a0747ed61f53d793b2611a5f72f/lib/net/protocol.rb#L227). If you open browser developer tools, you can see it under subtab response for request with status 500 under tab Network.

Error reason: library can not connect to your smtp server that according to your `development.rb` config `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` is located at `localhost:3000`. At port 3000 is located your web-server, smtp usually is located at port 25, 587, 2525 (if it is running).

You need **running smtp server** and **correctly configured** `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` on your local computer if you wish to send mail to `my-email-address@email.com` in development environment.

If you wish to check email, you can look at console or log. Or use gem letter_opener, or use `ActionMailer::Preview`. See [answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301389/how-to-see-e-mail-views-in-browser-using-rails).